# How did John Henry take Cameron’s chip to the future?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

Near the end of the first episode of *Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles* season 1, "Pilot," John Connor, Sarah Connor and Cameron are in the vault of a bank, assembling a time machine to go to future, and have the following conversation (as per the Terminator Wiki):

> John: So you just have like a account here?
>
> Cameron: Safety deposit box.
>
> Sarah: When did you open that?
>
> Cameron: 1963. (walks by an engraving that says, "THIS STONE WAS SET
> 1963 THIS DAY MARCH 7")
>
> John: Is that from the future?
>
> **Cameron: Can't bring anything through when you come. Not weapons, not clothing. Nothing. You send someone back to build it.**

As per Cameron’s last sentence, when anyone time travels, they cannot bring anything with them.

But in the last episode of season 2, "Born to Run," Cameron came to Catherine Weaver's building looking for John Henry. When she found him, he asked her:

> **"Will you join us?"**

[image: Image of John Henry and Cameron from S02E22 of "Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles."]

Cameron then pulled a knife out of her pocket, removed her chip, and gave it to John Henry, who traveled to the future with it (most of this occurred off-screen, but was relayed through subsequent dialogue).

So my question is: if they cannot bring anything with them when time travelling, how did John Henry bring Cameron's chip? Did he use his chip port to take Cameron’s chip to the future?

Comment: Yeah. It was in his head. He had no other means; he was an AI run by computers behind him.

Comment: One possibility was covered in the movies - a Terminator can travel through time because they are covered in living flesh. Presumably, then, they could also hide a small object under their skin if needed, and just dig it out after they arrive.

Comment: @Omegacron, you can give a answer with proof.. why commenting?

Comment: @RANSARA009 - full answers are too much work.

Comment: Makes you wonder why they didn't GMO artificial meat to grow in travel-case form from the beginning...although a meat capsule schlopping open would be less cool than the photoflash sphere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the 'John Henry' ([T-888](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Series_888)) body was simply a puppet of the Turk/John Henry computer (and connected by a wire to the wall where the controlling computer was located) it's most likely that the Turk inserted Cameron's ([T-900](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/T-900_(The_Sarah_Connor_Chronicles))) chip into the chip slot, ceding control of the John Henry body to Cameron who then time-traveled to some point in the future to continue the war against Skynet.

[image]

Given the similarity of model type, (T-888 vs T-900) there's no real reason to assume the chips weren't directly compatible.

Comment: Is that means Cameron & John henry same Model Chip Type..

Comment: @RANSARA009 - Yes, or at least broadly compatible.

Comment: I thought it was fairly clear that John Henry timetraveled, not Cameron. The T1000 seemed to believe that. I assumed John Henry copied himself to the chip to become mobile. Cameron was either dead or submerged, thus the “sorry.”

Comment: Additionally, John Henry has been created as a super-AI “brother” to Skynet as part of the nebulous Connor/T1000 scheme. Sending Cameron to the future gains them nothing, the Resistance already has her and other T800s. Sending John Henry saves him from Skynet’s attempts to destroy him in the past and effectively “hides” him and likely puts a super-AI on the side of humanity and T1000s.

Answer (score 0):

ok this is how it went down for the record. Cameron gave John Henry her to place in his head and then transferred Cameron to the server and John Henry was transferred from the server to the chip, with all that Cameron had learned. That is why the server was say I'm sorry john because it was Cameron on the server. When john and the others went to the future after John Henry he ended up skipping over John Conner building the resistance Fighters from the ground up. So now someone else took his place in history. But who...not the Reese boys since they was too young most likely. The reason they are alive is because John Conner never was there to send them back in time, yet.

Comment: Does this information come from an official source, or is this an explanation you came up with on your own? If it is from an official source, you could make this answer more authoritative by citing the source.

Comment: @LogicDictates - I'm pretty sure that this is their own headcanon

Comment: Not official but only thing that makes any logical sense.